# Download, unzip and parse xml into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I have a python script that downloads, unzip and parses an XML file published by a Canadian institution. Only some very specific tags are extracted and then all put into a pandas dataframe for later processing.

Everything works well. I just wonder if there is room for improvement here, specially in the parsing part. I am not sure if the nested `for` I use are a good idea or there is a better and cleaner way to parse.

```
import requests
import zipfile
import os
import glob
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO, BytesIO
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def download_file(url,filename):
    r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
    open(filename, 'wb').write(r.content)

def unzip_and_delete(filename):
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(filename,'r')
    zip_file.extractall()
    zip_file.close()
    os.remove(filename)

def parse_xml_fields(file, base_tag, tag_list,final_list):
    root = etree.parse(file)
    nodes = root.findall("//{}".format(base_tag))
    for node in nodes:
        item = {}
        for tag in tag_list:
            if node.find(".//{}".format(tag)) is not None:
                item[tag] = node.find(".//{}".format(tag)).text.strip()
        final_list.append(item)

# My variables
field_list = ["MsbRegistrationNumber","StatusDescriptionEnglish","Surname","GivenName","MiddleName","Name","StreetAddress"]
entities_list = []


download_file('http://www10.fintrac-canafe.gc.ca/msb-esm/public/msb-search/zipdownload-eng/', 'fintrac.zip')

unzip_and_delete('fintrac.zip')

parse_xml_fields("MsbRegistryPublicDataFile.xml", "MsbInformation", field_list, entities_list)

df = pd.DataFrame(entities_list, columns=field_list)

df.to_excel("Canada_MSB_List.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You are traversing the tree searching for the same element twice* - once when checking if it exists and then to get the text. You can do it once and find a text with [`.findtext()`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementTree-class.html#findtext) directly:

```
for node, tag in itertools.product(nodes, tag_list):
    node_text = node.findtext(".//{}".format(tag))
    if node_text is not None:
        final_list.append({tag: node_text.strip()})
```

Other notes:

- remove unused imports and structure them according to PEP8 ([reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports))
- use `with` context managers when opening a file and zip file
- it would be cleaner if `parse_xml_fields()` would return a list of results instead of modifying an input list

Comment: Thanks, aside from the main explanation about traversing the tree, I found useful your other notes to get my code cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

You may `import itertools` and then replace the part

```
for node in nodes:
    item = {}
    for tag in tag_list:
        if node.find(".//{}".format(tag)) is not None:
            item[tag] = node.find(".//{}".format(tag)).text.strip()
    final_list.append(item)
```

with

```
for node, tag in itertools.product(nodes, tag_list):
    if node.find(".//{}".format(tag)) is not None:
        final_list.append({tag: node.find(".//{}".format(tag)).text.strip()})
```

as `itertools.product()` creates a *cartesian product* of your two lists (and so the temporary dictionary `item` is no longer needed).

Comment: Thanks but I see something strange: this `itertools.product` approach is creating a new dictionary per every `tag` match found, when my previous method would create a dictionary containing all `tag` matches for one `node`. So for instance, if an entity has 7 tags, rather than one dictionary with 7 keys, I am getting 7 dictionaries with one key.

Comment: For such small number of tags and nodes, when moreover the most consuming time are network transfers, it has no importance - the readability has, however (IMHO).